# What is the condition for Mobile app install ad with CPA bideding?

Tags: mobile, curl, ads, facebook-ads-api, adgroup

What is the condition to create mobile app install ad with CPA?
When I upload Mobile app install ad with CPA bidding, I got this error message:

> Your account does not have enough install history to start using cost
>   per action (CPA) bidding for mobile app install ads

Request:

```
curl -d "name=Mobile app&bid_type=CPA&bid_info={'ACTIONS':1}..."
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> You will not be able to buy CPA for mobile app installs unless you
>   have already reported back some installs and your account id-app
>   id-mobile store trio has been deemed non-fraudulent. In the meantime,
>   your ad creation call will fail.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/

Comment: Thanks Paul! But how can we check the app has some install or not?
From adstats?

Comment: You can likely take a look at the insights page for the app under developer.facebook.com/apps and there is a report under insights I think. I'm not sure through the API.

Comment: Ok, understand! Will check it.

Comment: How can I report back installs?

Comment: using the FB SDK for Android or iOS https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events

Comment: I think the documentation poses more questions than it answers. How does one prove one's app isn't fraudulent? How many is 'some' installs? Do the installs have to be from a paid ad or just any install reported by the API? Why doesn't it tell you the steps to meet these conditions which they haven't publicly defined?